# How to use regex literals in binding expressions?

Tags: regex, angularjs

Essentialy I can't use

```
<li ng-repeat="list in per_letter|filter:search">{{text.replace(/\d/g, "")}}</li>
```

I get an error in the console:
Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20…acter%20&p1=s%2015-15%20%5B%5C%5D&p2=movie.replace(%2F%5Cd%2Fg%2C%20%22%22)

Maybe it's not meant to be...

Comment: I don't know what I can add to explain better than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why cant you use another filter for this?

```
app.filter('replace', function(){
    return function(obj){
        return obj.replace(/\d/g, "");
    }
});

<li ng-repeat="list in per_letter|filter:search">{{text |replace}}</li>
```

Comment: Ok, I thought I could use it in that way